# Need Help Refactoring to D3.js V5 (from V2)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, refactoring, data-visualization

I am trying to refactor my code to make it compatible with d3.js v5 (it's working fine with v2).

I am combing through the documentation here but I am still getting confused.
https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Here is my original code block (D3.js v2):

```
<script src="js/libs/d3.v2.js"></script>

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .sort(null)
  .size([width, height])
  .children(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .value(function(d) { return d.radius * d.radius; })
  .nodes({values: d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.cluster; })
    .entries(nodes)});
```

That works fine. But when I make the following changes ...

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-format.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v3.min.js"></script>

// var pack = d3.layout.pack()
var pack = d3.pack()
  .sort(null)
  .size([width, height])
  .children(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .value(function(d) { return d.radius * d.radius; })
  .nodes({values: d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.cluster; })
    .entries(nodes)});
```

I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d3.pack(...).sort is not a function
```

I'm a bit confused because I made the change from `d3.layout.pack()` to `d3.pack()` ...

Here is a snapshot of my csv:

```
index | name | rating | type | city | state | ...
1.      bob.    7.       man.   nyc.    ny
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated

Comment: I believe you can simply strike the sort line out, but you'll still likely have other issues. Can you share a portion of the data, or at least its structure, to allow a more fulsome answer?

Comment: @Andrew Reid thank you for responding. if i comment that line out, it then goes to the next TypeError: d3.pack(...).size(...).children is not a function
    at makeGrap

Comment: Yes, I figured - but that's why I suggested adding some data or a description of its structure so that an answer can better address all the issues in moving from d3v2 to d3v5 here, otherwise an answer might be more speculative.

Comment: @AndrewReid understood. I included a small snapshot of the csv file (title row and first row of data) to give you an idea of the heirarchy.

Comment: @AndrewReid If this isnt sufficient I can include more data - it's just a very long file

Comment: @AndrewReid the documentation brought me to this example which I'm trying to model (which may or may not be helpful to you) https://observablehq.com/@d3/circle-packing

Comment: Can you include about 10 lines of the csv, and indicate what the hiearchy represents,  (I am assuming state parents, city children, and name grandchildren/leafs?)

Comment: @AndrewReid so I did a little trial & error and now my console is reading an error outside  this function (nothing yet still populating on the page because I need to solve that error first but what I did was var pack = function (data) { 
  return d3.pack()
    .size([width, height])
    // .padding(3)
    (d3.hierarchy({ children: data })
    // .sum(function (d) { return d.value; })); };
      .value(function(d) { return d.radius * d.radius; })
      .nodes({values: d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.cluster; })
        .entries(nodes)}) 
      )};

Comment: @AndrewReid looks like a mess here (sorry about that). I believe this should work ...(?) ... but if not I will be sure to include 10 lines of data like you asked